# Check values in multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to check some fields in table if they are null or have something and return result in one column.

For example:

```
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+  
| Field1      | Field2     |  Filed3     | Field4     |
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+  
| 1           | 2          |      3      |            |                 
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

Pseudocode for query:

```
IF field1 has value THEN  
    PRINT status1  
ELSE IF field2 has value THEN  
    PRINT status2  
ELSE IF field3 has value THEN  
    PRINT status3  
ELSE IF field4 has value THEN
    PRINT status4
```

How to get those status in one field?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "has value" means "not null", then you can use `case` like this:

```
select (case when field1 is not null then status1
             when field2 is not null then status2
             when field3 is not null then status3
             when field4 is not null then status4
        end)
```

Usually in SQL, you use `select`, not `print` to get results from tables.

Comment: But in this case if all field have something written then the status will be status1, not status4.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. I've little bit change your code to check if field is null. That is what I need.

Comment: @Josef . . . As for your first comment, this code does what you pseudo-code suggests should be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just wanting the first non-NULL field, I would take a look at the COALESCE function

```
SELECT COALESCE(Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4) AS Status
```

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php

Comment: Maybe I didn't explained very well... The final result should be the frist column that is empty. If you look at my table you should see that Field4 is empty. The result should be like "Field 4 is empty". If for example only filed 1 and 2 have some values then the output should be like "Field 3 is empty"...

Comment: Yes, I wasn't 100% certain of your intent - if you just want to identify the specific column with the NULL, Gordon's will be the correct answer. COALESCE is worth remembering if you ever want to manipulate the actual data, return a default if NULL, etc.